# Add a tickbox to on-hold/closed question edit area to signify the edit is not to resurrect/re-open

Tags: feature-request, review, edits

Edits performed to *on-hold* and *closed* questions which are *not intended as a re-open attempt* should not send the question to the re-open queue.
Currently there is no way to identify this.

The current function, which automatically sends an edited on-hold/closed question to the re-open queue, frequently sends questions where the edits don't change the scope of the question at all, and are mostly just basic, and often trivial, grammatical changes.
(I don't propose to *change* this function in any way)

This is frustrating for reviewers, and no control for editors.

Whenever possible, the re-open queue should be only to identify if the re-open attempt is valid, not to check if the edit was intended as a re-open attempt or not.

---

### Proposal

- In the question edit area, when editing *on-hold/closed* question
  only, add a new tick box which when ticked signifies that the current
  edit is *not* intended to resurrect/re-open the question.
- If ticked, the question edit will not invoke the question being sent to the
  re-open queue.

**Visual Example:**

[image]

---

### What if someone ticks the box by accident?

In that case, of if they misunderstood it, or any other reason, there is a "vote to re-open" button which can be pushed any time.

---

### The best option is not possible

This is not a proposal, just here for potential discussion.

I really wanted to suggest the more logical approach - a tick box which when ticked signifies the edit *is* an attempt to re-open the question. So nothing is sent to re-open queue unless *explicitly specified by the editor*.

However, for that to work it would mean removing the current function which automatically sends questions to the re-open queue, and that is too big a change.
There might be too many re-open attempts missed by users not being aware of the change, and still believing the question will go in the re-open queue.

My actual proposal doesn't stop questions going to the re-open queue from users who cannot be bothered to click the box, or forget, or do not see it, etc.
This *non-proposal* would catch all that and be much better.

As such, I put this non-proposal here as a discussion point in case people/Stack feel removing the current auto system would be acceptable.

Comment: Note that not everybody can vote to reopen a question. However, in the very unlikely event of somebody accidentally clicking the box, I would consider it acceptable to make a dummy edit to trigger the reopening (or one could just ask a user with sufficient reputation in chat). Also – this isn’t the case already (I cannot find this right now) –, it would be good if the reopen dialogue shows all changes since the question was first voted to close, in cases where making the question viable was a cumulative effort spanning more than one edit.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft "Note that not everybody can vote to reopen a question" Not directly with the votes, no, but I'm not sure how privileges work when editing an on-hold/closed question - it might go into re-open queue regardless of editors rep level. So depending on how that works, the new tick box only needs to be shown to users with [whatever] privilege is required to push an on-hold/closed question into the re-open queue following an edit (or show to all users if no such threshold exists).

Answer (score 4):

Your proposal here is long and well thought out, but you're missing a key identifier. What problem, exactly, are you trying to solve here? The reopen queue itself is already kept up-to-date and is usually empty, so it's not like there is any real need to minimize what is being seen there. Further, there is absolutely **no harm** in seeing a minor edit in there which triggered a review action. The only thing I've seen from you for why we would need this feature is:

> This is frustrating for reviewers, and no control for editors.

How is it frustrating? And how would this make it *any less* frustrating? There are still going to be people using minor edits to intentionally bump questions into the reopen queue, and this checkbox is not going to stop them.

But the fact that the edit is minor should really have no bearing on your decision in the review. The changes are shown to you because it makes it easier to see what has been improved since it was closed, **but that should not be the only thing you look at**. Some of those questions might not have deserved to be closed in the first place.

So all in all, I don't see a change like this being useful or necessary.

---

**Side note:** Do we have any stats on how many people *would* actually use this? As far as I know, most people who attempt to edit a closed question *want* it to be reopened, and editing solely for the purpose of editing is somewhat rare.

Comment: Surely it's good practice to have a system tight and behaving as required/necessary? Rather than just shoving anything and everything to the re-open queues. I see various edits in the re-open queue on closed questions which were arguably pointless edits in themselves, let alone sending it to a re-open queue.

Comment: @James Sure there are, and there still will be with your proposed change. As I said, there will always be people making minor edits just to bump their question or push it into the Reopen queue. It seems like the specific edits you're targeting would not be affected by this change, because those people wouldn't want to check that box.

Comment: Well, of course the feature cannot resolve everything. just the same as people will always post off-topic questions, or vote for the wrong reasons, etc. I'm not suggesting this will change the world, just that it will weed out numerous pointless re-open review questions. Such as: http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/32251 - There, the editor could have ticked my proposed box as I doubt very much they intended to resolve the dupe issue, or gain some additional presence to the question.

Comment: @James So what? It got left closed. I don't see how the added complications in the system are worth such a rare and unimportant prevention.

Comment: @James the very reason there is a re-open queue is that not all edits are sufficient for the question to be re-opened. That is the point of it. Complaining that some of the things in the queue don't deserve to be re-opened is in fact stating that it's a good thing the queue exists and is patrolled by people who care and make good decisions.

Comment: @animuson "So what? It got left closed" It wasn't *left* closed, it was *voted* to remain closed by 3 users who reviewed it. Yes, the end result is fine, but part of my point is it's wasted reviewer time, not just "we got our end result yay!". It should never have been in the re-open queue in the first place, as no-one asked for it to be other than an *automated system* with a blanket-policy to send all edited closed questions to a review queue. For us all to decide if the user meant to re-open it or not. Why not let the editor decide that? Save us and the system some pointless work?

Comment: @James And I'm saying that the save timed is not worth the added complications. You're talking about a *very small* number of people who would actually use this. This is also only a **five-day timeframe** that edits bump them into the queue. It really feels like you're trying to kill a bug with a laser gun here.

Comment: @animuson "kill a bug with a laser gun" no, I was just trying to make an improvement. Your analogy could be used with many changes which Stack implement, and any other website/development team. Often changes are for small, tiny, insignificant outcomes, but are to streamline a system so it's designed and developed better. For now, and the future. Rather than "Meh, it'll do as it is, it's wrong, but whatever". It's wrong because edits are edits, and are not an attempt to re-open. An attempt to re-open should be signalled separately somehow.

Comment: @KateGregory Yes, but not all questions in the re-open queue are intentionally re-open requests, they were just plain old edits. Edits do not by themselves signify that the editor is attempting to re-open the questions. The very reason there is a re-open queue is to allow re-open *requests* to be checked and voted on by X community members. An edit on a question should not be automatic cause for a re-open request. They are separate actions. And the edits which are not re-open requests, and are just "edits" should not be sent to the review queue.

Comment: @James No one said the edit was an attempt to reopen. The system just sees that there was an edit and thinks "Hey, this got some attention and was supposedly improved. Maybe someone should look at it." Whether or not someone was *trying* to reopen it is irrelevant. It is **not** assuming the editor intended for it to be reopened - it's only bringing extra eyes to it, and there is absolutely nothing wrong with that. You say it's "wrong" and I disagree. I don't see a problem. A simple system which catches a few bad eggs is far better than a complicated system that tries to pinpoint exact posts.

Comment: @animuson I know how the system works, I'm arguing against it! "*this got some attention and was supposedly improved*" Yes, improved - so what? That's what *edits* are for, but edit != re-open! "Improve" can mean a LOT of things. What if it gets a comment, or an upvote? Should it be rushed right into the re-open queue to be evaluated? No, neither should it from an edit. "*Maybe someone should look at it*" Yes, if it was stated by the editor "I'm trying to re-open this", but an edit does not state that.

Comment: @James If you want people to explicitly state that they think a question should be reopened, then you might as well just implement a flag for reopen. But wait, Stack Exchange doesn't want to do that. Sometimes an edit can be an indicator, and I said before - **there's nothing wrong with people taking a look at it**. I don't know why you're so hung up on preventing things from hitting that queue. It really *isn't* a problem. You just keep saying "an edit is not a request to reopen" over and over and it's not going anywhere. So what?

Comment: All I can say is if you don't want to see minor edits in the Reopen queue and "waste your time" there, then don't review Reopen Votes. This feature *really isn't* worth the effort.

Comment: "*Whether or not someone was trying to reopen it is irrelevant*" - So, whether it was intended to be re-opened or not is irrelevant to deciding whether to send it to the "*re-open*" queue or not? Surely that's the opposite of good system management? "*A simple system which catches a few bad eggs is far better than a complicated system that tries to pinpoint exact posts*" What you said is very generic, and in some cases I'd agree, but I disagree it suits this particular scenario. A system which sends questions to a "re-open" queue to evaluate if they are "intended" as re-open is a little poor.

Comment: @animuson "don't review Reopen Votes" I'll bite my tongue on that one, my being part of the community which drives the "community driven" website. Thanks for the feedback anyway.